# Replace apply with operator

Tags: scala, implicit

I have the following trait

```
trait Tr{
  def process(query: String)
}

object Tr{
  @inline def apply(implicit l: Tr): Tr = l
}
```

And I wanted to import some object with implicit value and call it like this:

```
implicit val qpe: Tr = (i: String) => ()
val q: String = //some query
Tr.process(q)  //compile error
Tr.apply.process(q)  //OK!
```

But in ScalaZ we have the following object:

```
object Functor {
  @inline def apply[F[_]](implicit F: Functor[F]): Functor[F] = F
  //...
}
```

And the call

```
Functor[List].lift((_: Int) + 3)
```

works just fine. What's the difference?

Comment: Can you share the code for the implicit that implements `Tr` which you're trying to implicitly create?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Sure! Done.

Comment: You could write `def apply()(implicit l: Tr): Tr = l` and `Tr().process(q)`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Agree, but I wanted to use similar with `FunctorSyntax` pattern.

Comment: You can get the same call syntax by also defining `def process(query: String)(implicit l: Tr) = l.process(query)` in `object Tr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually rather interesting. It seems the trick is the type argument. When you do

```
Tr.process(...)
```

it looks in the `Tr` object for a method called `process`, which it fails to find. This is where the search stops. However, `Functor` takes a type argument. Now, singleton objects can't have type arguments, so when you write `Functor[List]`, Scala infers that you simply *must* be calling the `apply` method and starts looking for implicits. This theory can be verified by adding a dummy type argument to your `Tr` object's `apply`.

```
trait Tr[F] {
  def process(query: String)
}

object Tr {
  @inline def apply[F](implicit l: Tr[F]): Tr[F] = l
}
```

Now, when you try to invoke `Tr[Int].process(...)`, you can't possibly be referring to the object `Tr` alone, since it can't have a type argument, so Scala converts this to `Tr.apply[Int].process(...)` and everything works from there.

I'm not sure if there's a way to get the implicit behavior without forcing a type argument, and using a dummy argument is obviously undesired. But this seems to be the difference between your code and that of Scalaz.